# Javascript - while loop doesn't show success option

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Why my code never alerts "be happy"?

It works for every other option, but not this one. Why so?

```
var i = "";
while (i != "YES"){
    if(i == "NO"){
        alert("You should be!");
    }

    else if(i == "YES") {
        alert("Be happy!")
    }

    else{
        if(i == ""){
        }
        else {
            alert("C'mon dude... Answer simply yes or no!");
        }
    }

    i = prompt("Are You happy?").toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: How can `i == 'Yes'` in a `i != 'Yes'` loop before you alter `i` in that loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
When the user is prompted to write down "YES", you exit the while loop. Put it on top

var i = "";
while (i != "YES"){
    i = prompt("Are You happy?").toUpperCase(); //*************** Put it here
    if(i == "NO"){
        alert("You should be!");
    }

    else if(i == "YES") {
        alert("Be happy!")
    }

    else{ //Not needed (do else { alert("com...")} )
        if(i == ""){
        }
        else {
            alert("C'mon dude... Answer simply yes or no!");
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because when you enter the loop, the condition just ensure that `i` will never be `'Yes'` when the loop starts.

Pull your `i = prompt("Are You happy?").toUpperCase();` to the start of the loop.

Comment: And in this case, I suggest use `do while` ,as the logic in this is to ensure that the loop been executed at least once.